# MVC 5 Controller List Pass to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have the following code in the controller portion of an MVC5 project.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {


        insightly Insightly = new insightly(xxxxx);


        String Contact;
        var IContact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Insightly.GetContacts().ToString());
        // var IContact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(insightly.GetContact(CONTACT_ID).ToString());

        List<string> Contacts = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in IContact)
        {
            Contact = item.SALUTATION;

            Contacts.Add(Contact);

        }
        Response.Write(Contacts.Count);



        return View(Contacts);
    }
```

Everything works great, but I am having trouble with the Razor syntax on the view side for the DropDown box. 
Has anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a List of type string, return a List of type SelectListItem. Iterate over your contacts and add a selectlistitem for each contact e.g.:

```
   List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
   foreach (var contact in Contacts)
   {
      listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
      {
         Text = contact,
         Value = contact
      });
   }
```

In View:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("NameForList", 
                Model.listItems,
                "Please Choose",
                new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thank You...as you can probably guess, I am learning this as I go.

Comment: I implemented this...but the dropdown list is throwing an error           
        Here is the Razor Code                                                                            @Html.DropDownList("NameForList", (SelectList)Model.listItems, "Please Choose", new { @class = "form-control" })                                                                                      
        Additional information: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' does not contain a definition for 'listItems'    Any Idea?

Comment: Replace"Model.listItems" with just Model should fix that

Comment: OK...Solved.  I changed the controller to put the JSON results in a Viewbag List and used this syntax                            
                @Html.DropDownList("Contacts", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Contacts, "Choose a Person", new { @class ="extra-class" }) .  As Always , Thank You for your help!